virt-manager - Bridged network does not work on Debian 12
My host is debian 12 and I used virt-manager for the virtualization. My guest is Kali Linux.
I'm using an Ethernet connection and I need to use a bridge network to connect to an internal machine in my network.
So on my host, I edited my /etc/network/interfaces as follows:
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports enp0s31f6
bridge_hw <enp0s31f6 MAC ADDRESS>

My source for this is: https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/115f64u/debian_12_bookworm_network_bridging_for_kvm_vm/
You can see the VM configuration below:

Maybe my host firewall blocks something so I installed firewalls and I added the following rules:
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD -o br0 -j ACCEPT
systemctl restart firewalld

source: https://forums.opensuse.org/t/firewall-blocks-internet-on-bridge-in-kvm-virtual-machine/138737/6
Unfortunately, it changed nothing.
